# Subgroups of $F^*$ are cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory

> Q: If $F$ a field then every finite subgroup of $F^*$ is cyclic.

Solution: Suppose $d\mid |G|$ for $G$ subgroup of $F^*$ and $G$ not cyclic. Suppose $A,B$ subgroups of $G$ of order $d$. Then $|A\cup B|>d$ and every $x\in A\cup B$ satisfies $x^d=1$ so $f(x)=x^d-1$ has more that $d$ roots which is a contradiction. So for every $d\mid |G|$ there is at most one subgroup of order $d$ which implies $G$ cyclic.

Is my solution complete or did I miss something?

Comment: Perhaps you need to justify the existence of two subgroups of order $d$ whose union has more than $d$ elements? (Use the fact that $G$ is a finite abelian group.)

Comment: You need to explain the uniqueness of sugroup of order $d$ for $d | |G|$ implies $G$ is cyclic. For me this can be done by the structure of finite abelian groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should include the word "distinct" when introducing your subgroups ("Suppose $A,B$ are *distinct* subgroups of order $d$...").  Otherwise, this is good.

Comment: Congrats on the 20k. I feel that I can somehow trust you now. ;-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Haha, thanks - that's a line I've crossed and recrossed many times now, though. :)

Comment: Makes sense, what with 5000+ points given in bounties (and 550 on active bounties). Just remember that each time you do that, I stop trusting you (modulo your diamond ring). ;-)

Comment: I feel that I can't trust you anymore. Maybe if someone were to upvote you, then I might be able to trust you again! ;-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ahh, restored to my throne.

Comment: I'll just wait until the next bounty that you give. ;-)